# Telegram Bot (Telegraf) stuck in infinite loop

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, telegram, telegraf

My function named **status** sending information about products that are stored in **Firebase Realtime Database**. When user ask my bot for status then Firebase function get data from DB and then send back Telegram message for **every** of product that the user is assigned. For some users this can **take some time** even 2 minutes.

When **1st** user asks bot for status and bot function run for the first time everything is fine.

BUT when **2nd** user ask for status **during first call** of bot function (*when function still running for 1st user*) first call run **start over** and after first call is done finally second call are handled.

When **3rd** user calls function when old calls are not finished, everything **stacking on** and finally everything loops **until all calls of function are over**. Because bot has almost **2000 active users** this above problem runs into "infinite" loop because constantly some of users calls "status" for themselves.

This situation causes that users getting **almost infinite numbers of messages**.

I'm using JavaScript & Node 12 on Firebase.

```js
const { Telegraf, Markup } = require('telegraf');
const { telegrafThrottler } = require('telegraf-throttler');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const debug = true;

admin.initializeApp(); // initialize firebase-admin

const bot = new Telegraf(functions.config().telegram_token.key); // initialize Telegraf bot
const throttler = telegrafThrottler(); // Telegraf Throttler
bot.use(throttler);


/**
 *
bot.command('some_commands_here', async (ctx) => {
    const nothing = 'THIS IS NOT IMPORTANT';
});
bot.command(...) more commands
 */

/** action with infinite loop problem */
bot.action('status', async (ctx) => {
    const uid = ctx.update.callback_query.from.id;
    let userData = await getUserAccountData(admin, uid); // get some data from firebase realtime db
    if (userData !== null) {
        let userProducts = await getUserProducts(admin, uid); // get some data from firebase realtime db
        if (userProducts !== null) {
            // userProducts contain even 200 items for one user
            for (const [privateProductId, privateProductData] of Object.entries(userProducts)) {
                // some not important logic that create message and keyboard context
                // after this bot send informations about every product (can be even 200 messages )
                await bot.telegram.sendMessage(uid, `${message}`, {
                    parse_mode: 'html',
                    reply_markup: keyboard.reply_markup,
                });
            }
        }
    }
    // some not important logic if userData / userProducts are null
});



/** Default response for undefinded msg/commands */
bot.on('message', (ctx) => ctx.reply("Use /help if You don't know commands!"));

/** bot catch errors here */
bot.catch((err, ctx) => {
    if (debug) {functions.logger.error(`Bot Catched ERROR: ${err}`);}
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(123456789, `Bot Catched ERROR: ${err}`);
});

const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 500,
    memory: '1GB',
};
exports.bot = functions.region('europe-west3').runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // bot.handleUpdate(req.body, res);
    bot.handleUpdate(req.body, res).catch((err) => {
        if (debug) {functions.logger.error(err);}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK Finally I found cause ^^

I'm missed process.once in my code, because of that function was executed more than one time.

```js
process.once('SIGINT', () => bot.stop('SIGINT'));
process.once('SIGTERM', () => bot.stop('SIGTERM'));
```